# Is there anyway to Get the Value of a Variable that is a Value of a different Variable

Tags: javascript, sphero

Basically I am making a pokemon style game and When a move gets Assigned I wanted to know if there is anyway to take the Value of a string variable. And get the value of the variable that has the same Name as the string. Which sounds complicated but hopefully this makes it Make Sense.

```
var Move = 'Tackle';
var Tackle = Value Here;
```

I want to be able to take whatever the Variable Move is Equal to and get the Value that is labeled after it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use dynamic variable names in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117127/use-dynamic-variable-names-in-javascript)

Comment: I think so I am going to try it, Thanks so much!